# Error Correcting Codes definition explanation of q

Tags: coding-theory

[image: Error Correcting Codes]

I'm trying to understand this.

So, this is an algorithm for the Error Correcting Code.

This is a definition where n is the length of the vectors.
K is the dimension of a finite set from q to n
d is the minimum distance.

What is q?

Thank you

Comment: q is the number of elements in the field $F$

Comment: It's in the definition. Do you know what $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$ means? Also, this question is not related to the error function at all.

Comment: Fnq is a finite set with n as the length of vectors and q the maximum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

q is the number of characters in your alphabet. For example, a q of 2 would correspond to binary. 0 and 1 would be the only characters and your code words would be strings of 0s and 1s.

A larger q means more characters in use. q = 3 means the available characters are {0, 1, 2}, and a q of 5 would correspond to words like 01401204 and 33102402, where the available characters are {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}.

One way to think of it is like English. We have 26 letters that we string together to make our words. This would be a q of 26, although for mathematical reasons there is no field of size 26.

Comment: Thank you
so, n would take the values from 1 to q?

Comment: No, n is the length of the code @Lilz

Comment: Think of q as the number of letters in the alphabet, and n is the length of a given word. There are q=26 letters, but the word "butters" has n=7, and the word "antidisestablishmentarianism" has n = 28. The codes you refer to in your problem have a fixed length and a fixed alphabet size.

Comment: thank you! so, n is the length of each item in the set and q is the length of the set

Comment: Yup! The length of the set of characters specifically. Although we often say size, not length, when referring to the number of things a set.

Comment: I would say that in the usage given, $q$ is the number of characters in the alphabet but it is **very** important in this definition that the alphabet is actually a finite field, and not an arbitrary alphabet with $q$ characters.